# SQL Server Bulk Insert Conversion Fail

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am writing a function in C# to create a several Datatables and insert them into a Dataset, then using SQLBulkCopy to insert each Datatable into an Sql Server database. I get this error message: 
[image: Syste.InvalidOperationsException]

The exception happens at the column isBuget, which is a bit. The given value is type String? I clearly see 0 in the row I am adding.
    //create reamer table

```
        DataTable dtreamer = new DataTable();
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("quoteID");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("line");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("customer");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("salesman");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("quoteDesc");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("machineModel");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("machineDesc");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("isBudgetary");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("quoteDate");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("notes");
        dtreamer.Columns.Add("userName");

        dtreamer.Rows.Add(2016099, "Raise bore", "c", "sales", "desc",                                      
        "machineModel", "machineDesc", 0, "01/01/2000", "notes","userName");
```

I don't see any conversion. The debugger hits at the "WriteToServer" method of SQLBulkCopy.

```
   //create data set to hold tables
        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        set.Tables.Add(dtreamer);

        set.Tables.Add(dtlineitems);

        set.Tables.Add(dtcountries);

        set.Tables.Add(dtdiameters);

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                            copy.DestinationTableName = "Reamers";

                            copy.WriteToServer(dtreamer);
```

Comment: I see 0, not "0" int the Rows.Add method. Where do you see a string? What am I missing?

Comment: You didn't assign `SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings`. If you fail to do so, SQL Server assumes you are going to supply all columns in the table, in table order. It will *not* automatically map columns based on name. Add all columns you're using to the column mapping first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you are using `SqlBulkCopy` may be you should specify the column type for your each `DataTable` column like-

```
    DataTable dtreamer = new DataTable();
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("quoteID", typeof(int));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("line", typeof(string));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("customer", typeof(string));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("salesman", typeof(string));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("quoteDesc", typeof(string));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("machineModel", typeof(string));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("machineDesc", typeof(string));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("isBudgetary", typeof(bool));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("quoteDate", typeof(DateTime));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("notes", typeof(string));
    dtreamer.Columns.Add("userName", typeof(string));
```

And then try to add the row-

```
dtreamer.Rows.Add(2016099, "Raise bore", "c", "sales", "desc",                                      
"machineModel", "machineDesc", 0, "01/01/2000", "notes","userName");
```

Comment: Khairul...I know you are a guy, but I just wanted to say-  I love you man! You just made my day really great. Thanks!